# NGINX : redirecting non-www to www

Tags: nginx, web, dns, no-www

Could be the stupid one and could be most duplicate question ever asked.

But yes, I can't get this done.

I've one domain which is : example.co.in

I want to redirect to www.example.co.in

Server is : NGINX

My vHost config is:

```
server {
   listen         80;
   server_name example.co.in www.example.co.in;
   return 301 http://www.example.co.in$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen         80;
        server_name example.co.in www.example.co.in;

        access_log /var/www/example.co.in/public_html/logs/access.log; 
        error_log /var/www/example.co.in/public_html/logs/error.log; 

....
}
```

I've a A record entry for www in my dns server.

Edit:

I'm getting **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS** error

Any help would be help full.

Comment: Di you mean http request coming on example.co.in should be redirected to www.example.co.in ?

Comment: Yes exactly.....

Answer (score 0):

You have to `server` blocks with the same port and `server_name`s. It hits the first one and tells the requester to redirect to `www` which the requester makes another request to the same `server` block which starts the process over again.

If you want it to redirect to `www` then take `www` out of the first `server` block then reload or restart nginx.